# How does margin of separate element affect position of fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I have two separate `DIV`s one `position : fixed` for notification bar, and one for main container, when I give the `container` some `margin-top` , this also pushes my notification bar!

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zh9k8/2/

and, I know I can stick it to top of the page with `top : 0` but I want to know why does it happen.

Comment: Hmm, weird enough, if you throw a <br> in there, it will actually split the data like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Zh9k8/3/

Comment: These elements are placed in the body as well, correct?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Yes. how? you mean the margin is going to parent element?

Comment: No, the margin-top should only affect the positioning of the current div away from any other elements on the page. It's strange that the line break is not automatically occurring after the end tag of a div, it should do this without actually having to put one in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common issue caused by collapsing margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

The fix is to not use a margin, but create space another way. You could add top padding to `.container` and remove the margin:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zh9k8/4/

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first
> in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top
> border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.
>
> If the element's margins are collapsed with its parent's top margin,
> the top border edge of the box is defined to be the same as the
> parent's.

Very confusing lingo, but it describe's exactly what is happening.

Comment: This is good, why is that the fixed div did not create an automatic line break? After putting a break tag the margin was able to not affect the position of the fixed element... And I am saying that your answer is correct, I am just curious as to what happened to the automatic breaks.

Comment: Because a fixed positioned element is, by definition, completely removed from the document flow - all other elements around it act as if it is not there.

Comment: +1 for a good definition of fixed positions, I was having a hard time finding this information. So then in all essence, if you added the break tag, that is just as easily a fix as putting in a padding?

Comment: The behavior implies that the collapsed margin value becomes an attribute of the container, not the first child (thus offsetting the absolutely positioned element), but this doesn't seem to me to follow from the sentences you quoted above.  Can you clarify or point to the part of the spec that says this?

Comment: @JimGarrison - I didn't write the spec, I just quoted it. You are correct, the collapsed margin value does appear to become a property of the parent, and not the child. This is the closest line in the spec (just a few lines down from my link) that I could find `If the element's margins are collapsed with its parent's top margin, the top border edge of the box is defined to be the same as the parent's.` I probably would've worded it slightly differently, but it certainly states that the parent's top edge is now the same as the child's top edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use margins to create space.  And if you set minimal padding on the `body` it will eliminate the margin collapse with the fixed block.  See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMCc9/.

```
body {
    padding: 0.1px;
}
```

Comment: Seems mighty "hacky", but what isn't in CSS? Works like a charm!