# Why is the section with position set to fixed moving with the other section?

Tags: css, css-position

Note: Click full page when testing.

As you can see by the snippet, the section with the class "common" is set to a fixed position, but it seems to be relative to the other section.  How do I fix it so that the common section is fixed relative to the browser?

Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/my1c76vb/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=my1c76vb

Code:

HTML5:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Log in</title>
  <body>
        <section class="common">
      <header>
        <img src="resources/header.png" alt="Sqeaking Duck"/>
      </header>

      <aside class="menu">
        <h3>Guest</h3>
        <hr>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
    </section>
    <section class="login">
      <form action="loginManager.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Log in</legend>
          User: <input type="text" name="username" value="">
          <span class="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['state']) ? $_SESSION['userErr'] : '';?></span><br>
          Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="">
          <span class="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['state']) ? $_SESSION['passErr'] : '';?></span><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <p><span class="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['state']) ? $_SESSION['generalErr'] : '';?></span></p>
    </section>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
/*Common pages */
.common {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu h3 {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.menu hr {border-color: white;}

.menu nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

/*Log in page*/
.login {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

/*General*/
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: create one in https://jsfiddle.net/  and save and post a link here.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle.

Comment: the body needs a height. For ex. add height: 1000px; to body in css and see if thats what you are after. maybe height more than the browser window.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that the fixed element is having a margin-collapse. Google how to fix margin-collapsing. I added,

```
padding-top: 1px;
```

to the body.

Next I added,

`height: 2000px` to the body so the body can scroll and you can see the `position:fixed` in play

https://jsfiddle.net/my1c76vb/1/

Comment: I had seen margin-collapse while I was searching for an answer, but there were so many different kinds of situations that I couldn't translate a solution to my problem.  I'm still not sure why adding padding fixes the issue.  Since the common section has no margin set and is on a different layer than the other section, shouldn't it be at the top of the page regardless?

Comment: Thats why I use bootstrap or Normalizing css that these situations have already been tackled by great developers. I call those developers as legends.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want a layout which somewhat represents YouTubes layout (with a fixed header and a side bar).

The elements that have a fixed positioning are "lifted up" from the page so the rest of the page renders as if those elements wouldn't even be there. That in mind you have to adjust your layout a little:

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 150px; /*Same as header height*/
  margin-left: 150px; /*Same as menu width*/
}

.menu {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header></header>

<section class="container">
  <aside class="menu">
    <!-- Menu here -->
  </aside>

  <div class="content">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
</section>
```

- [Here is a demo](http://codepen.io/V-Kopio/pen/kXvoGv)

The content must have a margin (or padding) so that it wont get buried under the fixed elements.

Comment: It looks like if you remove `top: 0;` from header, then you get the same issue that I had.  Why is that?

Comment: [Here is some insight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560958/how-does-margin-of-separate-element-affect-position-of-fixed-element).

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*Common pages */
.common {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu h3 {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.menu hr {border-color: white;}

.menu nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

/*Log in page*/
.login {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top: 320px;
}

/*General*/
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Log in</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="common">
      <header>
        <img src="resources/header.png" alt="Sqeaking Duck"/>
      </header>

      <aside class="menu">
        <h3>Guest</h3>
        <hr>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
    </section>
    <section class="login">
      <form action="loginManager.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Log in</legend>
          User: <input type="text" name="username" value="">
          <span class="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['state']) ? $_SESSION['userErr'] : '';?></span><br>
          Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="">
          <span class="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['state']) ? $_SESSION['passErr'] : '';?></span><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <p><span class="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['state']) ? $_SESSION['generalErr'] : '';?></span></p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What else you need to do?

Comment: This doesn't make use of the fixed features though.  I know how to do relative.